# Calculate input/output rate for all interfaces which are part of GigabitEthernet102/

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to capture the sum of input rate and output rate for interfaces which are part of GigabitEthernet102.. I have some logic but would like assistance converting it to a suitable program to achieve this.

**INPUT**

```
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/1 is up, line protocol is up
  Interface state transitions: 5
  Hardware is GigabitEthernet/IEEE 802.3 interface(s), address is sets.sets.sets
  Description: xxx
  Internet address is x.x.x.x
 --More--             MTU 1514 bytes, BW 100000 Kbit (Max: 100000 Kbit)
     reliability 255/255, txload 0/255, rxload 0/255
  Encapsulation ARPA,
  Full-duplex, 100Mb/s, 1000BASE-T, link type is force-up
  output flow control is off, input flow control is off
  Carrier delay (up) is 100 msec, Carrier delay (down) is 100 msec
  loopback not set,
  Last link flapped 10w3d
  ARP type ARPA, ARP timeout 04:00:00
  Last input 00:00:00, output 00:00:00
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
  30 second input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
  30 second output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
     5638310 packets input, 467600021 bytes, 27 total input drops
     0 drops for unrecognized upper-level protocol
     Received 4 broadcast packets, 186012 multicast packets
              1 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles, 0 parity
     2 input errors, 1 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored, 0 abort
     4336700 packets output, 306662485 bytes, 0 total output drops
     Output 44 broadcast packets, 0 multicast packets
     0 output errors, 0 underruns, 0 applique, 0 resets
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out
     0 carrier transitions

GigabitEthernet102/0/0/2 is administratively down, line protocol is administratively down
  Interface state transitions: 0
  Hardware is GigabitEthernet/IEEE 802.3 interface(s), address is sets.sets.sets
  Internet address is Unknown
  MTU 1514 bytes, BW 100000 Kbit (Max: 100000 Kbit)
     reliability 255/255, txload 0/255, rxload 0/255
  Encapsulation ARPA,
 --More--             Full-duplex, 100Mb/s, 1000BASE-T, link type is force-up
  output flow control is off, input flow control is off
  Carrier delay (up) is 100 msec, Carrier delay (down) is 100 msec
  loopback not set,
  Last input never, output never
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
  5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
  5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
     0 packets input, 0 bytes, 0 total input drops
     0 drops for unrecognized upper-level protocol
     Received 0 broadcast packets, 0 multicast packets
              0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles, 0 parity
     0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored, 0 abort
     0 packets output, 0 bytes, 0 total output drops
     Output 0 broadcast packets, 0 multicast packets
     0 output errors, 0 underruns, 0 applique, 0 resets
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out
     0 carrier transitions

TenGigE0/2/0/3 is up, line protocol is up
  Interface state transitions: 3
  Hardware is TenGigE, address is sets.sets.sets
  Layer 1 Transport Mode is LAN
 --More--             Description:
  Internet address is x.x.x.x
  MTU 1536 bytes, BW 10000000 Kbit (Max: 10000000 Kbit)
     reliability 255/255, txload 0/255, rxload 0/255
  Encapsulation ARPA,
  Full-duplex, 10000Mb/s, LR, link type is force-up
  output flow control is off, input flow control is off
  Carrier delay (up) is 10 msec
  loopback not set,
  Last link flapped 18w3d
  ARP type ARPA, ARP timeout 04:00:00
  Last input 00:00:00, output 00:00:00
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters 10w1d
  5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 1 packets/sec
  5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 1 packets/sec
     3907990 packets input, 341219535 bytes, 0 total input drops
     10323 drops for unrecognized upper-level protocol
     Received 0 broadcast packets, 218445 multicast packets
              0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles, 0 parity
     0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored, 0 abort
     6795781 packets output, 490559886 bytes, 0 total output drops
     Output 0 broadcast packets, 0 multicast packets
     0 output errors, 0 underruns, 0 applique, 0 resets
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out
     0 carrier transitions

GigabitEthernet102/0/0/3 is up, line protocol is up
  Interface state transitions: 1
  Hardware is GigabitEthernet/IEEE 802.3 interface(s), address is x.x.x.x
  Description: xxx
  Internet address is x.x.x.x
  MTU 1514 bytes, BW 100000 Kbit (Max: 100000 Kbit)
     reliability 255/255, txload 0/255, rxload 0/255
  Encapsulation ARPA,
  Full-duplex, 100Mb/s, 1000BASE-T, link type is force-up
  output flow control is off, input flow control is off
  Carrier delay (up) is 100 msec, Carrier delay (down) is 100 msec
  loopback not set,
 --More--             Last link flapped 18w3d
  ARP type ARPA, ARP timeout 04:00:00
  Last input 00:00:00, output 00:00:00
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
  5 minute input rate 2000 bits/sec, 2 packets/sec
  5 minute output rate 1000 bits/sec, 2 packets/sec
     23543445 packets input, 2623268477 bytes, 66 total input drops
     18599 drops for unrecognized upper-level protocol
     Received 37519 broadcast packets, 225636 multicast packets
              0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles, 0 parity
     0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored, 0 abort
     24806600 packets output, 2739397694 bytes, 0 total output drops
     Output 3 broadcast packets, 0 multicast packets
     0 output errors, 0 underruns, 0 applique, 0 resets
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out
     0 carrier transitions
```

**SUGGESTED PROGRAM FLOW**

1> Capture interfaces which are UP and have GigabitEthernet102/[0-9]{3} syntax

GigabitEthernet102/0/0/1

GigabitEthernet102/0/0/3

2> Search file again with these interfaces (possibly positive lookbehind?) to capture input rate. Do the same thing for output rate.

3> Use array to perform sum of the input/output rates.

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
Total input traffic: x bits
Total output traffic: x bits
```

**ATTEMPTS**

```
   1> awk '/^GigabitEthernet102/ && !/down/' sat_int_acc.txt  

GigabitEthernet102/0/0/1 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/3 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/4 is up, line protocol is up
...

    2> awk '/^GigabitEthernet102/ && !/down/ {intf[$1]} END {for(i in intf) print i}' sat_int_acc.txt

GigabitEthernet102/0/0/30
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/21
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/12
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/40
...

    awk '/^GigabitEthernet102/ && !/down/; /^GigabitEthernet102/,/input rate/' sat_int_acc.txt
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The following does input and output rates, based on your attempt with regular expression ranges. It reads a block from a line starting with `GigabitEthernet102` and containing `is up` until a blank line or the end of file. Within each block it looks for `input rate` or `output rate` and sums the rates.

```
$ cat sat_int_acc.awk
/^GigabitEthernet102.* is up/,/^$/ {
        if (/input rate/) input_total += $5
        if (/output rate/) output_total += $5
}

END {
        print "Total input traffic: " input_total " bits"
        print "Total output traffic: " output_total " bits"
}
$ awk -f sat_int_acc.awk sat_int_acc.txt
Total input traffic: 2000 bits
Total output traffic: 1000 bits
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work with one `awk` command.

```
awk '/protocol is/ {f=0} /GigabitEthernet102.* is up/ {f=1} f && /5 minute/ {sum+=$5} END {print sum}' file
3000
```

- `/protocol is/ {f=0}` Test if start of new interface block and set flag `f` to `0`
- `/GigabitEthernet102.* is up/ {f=1}` if correct interface is found set flag `f` to `1`
- `f && /5 minute/ {sum+=$5}` if flag `f\ is true and line is`5 minute`
- `END {print sum}'` then print sum of bout input and output

NB you need to not mix `5 minute` and `30 second` input.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I might have found a solution, but it is not pure awk.

```
$  awk '/GigabitEthernet102.* is up/,/input rate/' sat_int_acc.txt | grep "input rate" | awk '{x+=$5}END {print x}'
```

43237000

Comment: That's crazy. Awk can do everything `grep` can do. See also [useless use of `grep`.](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)