# Attempting to match interfaces which are even using awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to capture the sum of input & output rate separately for even and odd interfaces.

```
   GigabitEthernet102/0/0/1 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/3 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/4 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/5 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/5.4096 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/6 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/7 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/8 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/10 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/10.4096 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/11 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/12 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/13 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/14 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/15 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/16 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/17 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/18 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/19 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/20 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/21 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/22 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/23 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/24 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/25 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/26 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/27 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/28 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/29 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/30 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/30.310 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/31 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/33 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/35 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/39 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/40 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/41 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/42 is up, line protocol is up
```

The following awk statement matches all the interfaces, but I would like to match only the even interfaces / odd interfaces so I can sum up the input and output rate.

```
$ awk '$0 ~ "^GigabitEthernet102/0/0/.* is up"'file.txt
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/1 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/3 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/4 is up, line protocol is up
```

The following commands do not match on even/odd interfaces. Can anyone suggest a solution?

```
$ awk '$0 ~ "^GigabitEthernet102/0/0/[0-9]%2 is up"' file.txt

$ awk '$0 ~ "^GigabitEthernet102/0/0/[0-9]%2==1 is up"' file.txt
```

**Original question:** (please check format of input/output rate here)
[Calculate input/output rate for all interfaces which are part of GigabitEthernet102/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57575371/calculate-input-output-rate-for-all-interfaces-which-are-part-of-gigabitethernet/57578692#57578692)

**Desired output:**

```
{logic to capture even ports}, /input rate/ {input_rate += $5}
                               /output rate/ {output_rate += $5}

{logic to capture odd ports}, /input rate/ {input_rate += $5}
                              /output rate/ {output_rate += $5}
```

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like the same question, is it?

Comment: you could use `match` as well, eg. `'match($0, "^GigabitEthernet102/0/0/([0-9]+)", m) {if (m[1]%2) print m[1]}'`

Comment: @user, Could you please clarify more on adding value part may be by adding real sample lines of input and expected output in your post.

Answer (score 1):

You may do:

```
awk '$0 ~ "^GigabitEthernet102/0/0/[0-9]*[13579] is up"' file
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/1 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/3 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/5 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/5 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/41 is up, line protocol is up
```

and

```
awk '$0 ~ "^GigabitEthernet102/0/0/[0-9]*[02468] is up"' file
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/4 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/42 is up, line protocol is up
```

Comment: Hi Jotne, your script works well but unfortunately does not work well on sub-interfaces. i.e. (GigabitEthernet102/0/0/10.4096). I have updated the full list of interfaces in the question.

Comment: @user do you get odd/even interface og subinterface number?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following(not sure about input and output rates OP's logic, so please add samples for same).

For Odd ones:

```
awk -F'/' '$1=="GigabitEthernet102" && $4%2!=0' Input_file
```

For even ones:

```
awk -F'/' '$1=="GigabitEthernet102" && $4%2==0' Input_file
```

EDIT:

For odd:

```
awk -F'[/.]'  '$1=="GigabitEthernet102" && $4%2!=0{odd+=$5+0} END{print odd}'  Input_file
```

For even:

```
awk -F'[/.]'  '$1=="GigabitEthernet102" && $4%2==0{even+=$5+0} END{print even}'  Input_file
```

Comment: Hi RavinderSingh13, your commands work well however do not work on sub-interfaces, i.e. (GigabitEthernet102/0/0/10.4096). I will update the full list of interfaces in the question.

Comment: @user, sure, let me know once updated, will update my answer too then.

Comment: Hi RavinderSingh13, it is updated. Can you please add the if logic too for calculating input/output rate into your answer? I can't seem to get the syntax right..

Comment: I tried this, but I get 0 after printing the total input. I suspect it's because I used semicolon, but if I omit it the awk parser complains.

$  awk -F'/' '$1=="GigabitEthernet102" && !/down/ && $4%2==0; /input rate/{input_total += $5} END {print input_total}' file.txt

Comment: awk: cmd. line:1: $1=="GigabitEthernet102" && !/down/ && $4%2==0 /input rate/{input_total += $5} END {print input_total}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                            ^ syntax error

Comment: @user, Do you want to add things after `.`? in `/` series?

Comment: RavinderSingh13 - yes, the numbers with dots must also be considered.

Comment: @user, please check my EDIT once and let me know then?

Comment: unfortunately it did not work:
$ awk -F'[/.]'  '$1=="GigabitEthernet102" && $4%2!=0{odd+=$5+0} END{print odd}' sat_int_acc.txt
4096
$ awk -F'[/.]'  '$1=="GigabitEthernet102" && $4%2==0{even+=$5+0} END{print even}' sat_int_acc.txt
4406

Comment: I ended up manually copying the odd and even interfaces, then running the script provided in the original question to get input/output rate for odd & even interfaces. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
awk '{ split($0,b," "); split(b[1],a,"/"); if (a[4]%2 == 0) print $0}' file.txt

GigabitEthernet102/0/0/4 is up, line protocol is up
GigabitEthernet102/0/0/42 is up, line protocol is up
```

:

Answer (score 0):

The `%` operator requires a number as input, and of course cannot be part of a regex.

```
awk '$1 ~ "GigabitEthernet102/0/0/[0-9]+" {
        split("/", x, $1); n = x[4] % 2 }
    /input rate/ { input_total[n] += $5 }
    /output rate/ { output_total[n] += $5 }
    END { for (n in input_total)
        printf "%s: input %i output %i\n",
            (n==0 ? "even" : "odd"),
            input_total[n], output_total[n] }' file.txt
```

The first line extracts the last item from the slash-separated interface name and uses that to calculate `n` using modulo; so `n` will be 0 or 1 on the subsequent iterations depending on which interface we last saw.

This calculates odd and even numbers in one go, which should be more efficient than looping over the same input file twice. You can postprocess the output if you need the results to be separate, or refactor it to only print odd or even output depending on a parameter.